# Arrange divs in ASC order based on child inputs value

Tags: jquery, sorting, return-value

How would you order divs based on a child inputs value? I want to eventually get this to work on keyup.

```
<div class="wrap_0">
    <input class="sort_by" value="10"/>
</div>
<div class="wrap_1">
    <input class="sort_by" value="3"/>
</div>
<div class="wrap_2">
     <input class="sort_by" value="7"/>
</div>
```

Change to:

```
<div class="wrap_0">
    <input class="sort_by" value="3"/>
</div>
<div class="wrap_1">
    <input class="sort_by" value="7"/>
</div>
<div class="wrap_2">
     <input class="sort_by" value="10"/>
</div>
```

My current jquery is not working:

```
var sortedArray = $("div[class^='wrap_']").get().sort(function(a, b) {
  var idx = parseInt($(a).find(".sort_by").value,10);
  var idx2 = parseInt($(b).find(".sort_by").value,10);
  return idx > idx2;
});
$(sortedArray).each(function() {
  $(this).appendTo("body");
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/E4U2V/3/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.val()` instead of `.value`.

`.val()` is the method to be used on jQuery objects. While `.value` on javascript objects.

```
 $(a).find(".sort_by")[0].value;
```

Also, there is no need of using `.each()` for appending the array.

---

```
var sortedArray = $("div[class^='wrap_']").get().sort(function(a, b) {
   var idx = parseInt($(a).find(".sort_by").val(),10);
   var idx2 = parseInt($(b).find(".sort_by").val(),10);
   return idx > idx2;
});
$(sortedArray).appendTo("body");
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/E4U2V/7/)**

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your quick response. Do you have any idea how I could deal with someone typing in the same number twice? Meaning, if they typed in 11 but 11 already exists, the like value and every value after it would increment by 1? So 9,11,11,12 would become 9,11,12,13. Thank again.

Comment: @Tushar, thank you, I wasn't able to merge your edit with my next, so the fiddle link remianed old one.